# Dynamically group options into opt-group using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using a payment gateway API where I am getting an array of data. There is one drop-down (select-option) for users to select their payment method using either Credit/Debit Cards or Other (eg. paypal) methods. I want to group all methods into two groups as "Credit/Debit Card" and "Other Method"
Using php(since API is in php) I am able to build a drop-down like:

```
<select id="cardname" name="ptype">
<option>Select Payment Method</option>
<option data-id="a" value="1">Visa</option>
<option data-id="a" value="2">American Express</option>
<option data-id="a" value="3">MasterCard</option>
<option data-id="a" value="114">Visa Debit</option>
<option data-id="a" value="119">Mastercard Debit</option>
<option data-id="a" value="122">Visa Electron</option>
<option data-id="a" value="125">JCB</option>
<option data-id="b" value="841">WebMoney</option>
<option data-id="b" value="843">Skrill (Moneybookers)</option>
</select>
```

I need a quick guidance to build an grouped drop-down box.

Answer (score 0):

One way you can group the options is by using `<optgroup>`. e.g.:

```
<select id="cardname" name="ptype">
  <option>Select Payment Method</option>
  <optgroup label="Credit Cards">
    <option data-id="a" value="1">Visa</option>
    <option data-id="a" value="2">American Express</option>
    <option data-id="a" value="3">MasterCard</option>
    <option data-id="a" value="114">Visa Debit</option>
    <option data-id="a" value="119">Mastercard Debit</option>
    <option data-id="a" value="122">Visa Electron</option>
    <option data-id="a" value="125">JCB</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="Other methods">
    <option data-id="b" value="841">WebMoney</option>
    <option data-id="b" value="843">Skrill (Moneybookers)</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

Is that what you are looking for? Hope that helps.

Comment: Unfortunately No. I am getting the values and text for option as an array. the 'data-id' is what makes the whole options into two groups. I want it to be done through jQuery.

Comment: Where do you want jQuery to set in: Do you want the data-array converted to select/optgroup/option scheme or do you want to modify your select-box after it has been printed by PHP?

Comment: The first option, I want the data-array converted to select/optgroup/option scheme. Second option is also an option. Which  will be the best? Please suggest.

Comment: I would suggest option 1, to convert the data array directly. Can you show us the structure of that array - this would make it easier to suggest an implementation with jQuery.